# How to create the same type component when clicked a component in react?

Tags: reactjs

I wanna create some children polygons when click a polygon. How can i do it? The first polygons created when map loaded.
in clickHandler method fetching some polygons coordinates from server.

```js
    clickHandler(id) {
        let areaType = 'city' // every clicked gonna change, assigned 'city for now
        axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/service/${areaType}/${id}/`)
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({areas: res.data})
            this.render() 
            
        })

    }


    render(){
        return (
            this.props.areas.map(area => 
                <Polygon
                    id={area.name}
                    key={area.id}
                    paths={area.coordinates}
                    name={area.name}
                    strokeColor={'#000000'}
                    strokeOpacity= {1}
                    strokeWeight={1.2}
                    fillOpacity={0.3}
                    fillColor= {'#00ff00'}
                    onClick={() => this.clickHandler(area.id)} 
                    areas={this.state.areas} //send new areas to create children polygons
                   
                >
                                 
                </Polygon>
            )
        )   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SVG Directly.  Re-write the question.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-dubinsky-1dpdj?file=/src/components/polygon.jsx here is all code.